# Internet Explorer range object constructor

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

From this documentation I can see range objects are supported in IE, with several methods. However what is not supported is its constructor; writing

```
var r = new Range();
```

Will cause an error. How do I create an empty range ( which I will then fill with .setStart and .setEnd ) in Internet Explorer?

Comment: could you use a polyfill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [`document.createRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) is the method you're looking for. However, there are a lot of inconsistencies and quirks when dealing with ranges and selections cross-browser. I'd encourage you to checkout the [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki) project which helps normalize a lot of the features of Ranges/Selections cross browser.

Good luck!

Comment: I have no idea how I could miss something so simple. Thanks a lot!